# Help understanding $D_{KL} (g;f)=0\iff f=g$ a.e.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, entropy

It's seems to be a well know property of the Kullback-Leibler divergence (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)) that 
$$D_{KL} (g;f)=0\iff f=g\,\,\, a.e.$$

I am working with the continuous case. The second implication is straightforward and I am more interested in the $``\implies"$ direction.

$$D_{KL}(g;f)=\int_{\mathbb R} \log\left(\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\right)g(x)dx=0$$
I don't quite graps how this implies $f=g$ a.e. 
The logarithm is not non-negative, and hence I don't know how to proceed.

I've read this follows from Gibb's inequality but I haven't been able to see how.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Here is the more rigorous proof based on measure theoritic argument. https://pwsiegel.github.io/ds/gibbs-inequality/

Comment: Thanks @viru I'll give it a look!

Comment: The KL divergence is just a particular Bregman divergence on the space of probability measures. The fact you're interested in is a property of Bregman divergences, i.e. that they are $0$ iff the arguments are equal in the vector space you are considering. In the space at hand, we have only equality among equivalence classes of functions which differ on a null set. So $f=g$ in the Bregman sense here means that $f=g$ a.e.

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the Jensen Inequality. Indeed by Jensen, we have
$$-D_{KL}(g;f)=\int_{\mathbb R} \log_2\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)g(x)dx \leq \log_2\left(\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g(x)dx\right)=\log_2(1)=0.$$
The equality holds iff a.e. $f(x)=g(x)$.

Comment: "the equality holds iff ..." That's precisely what I want to prove.

Comment: Note that the "iff" condition is the equality condition in Jensen Inequality and it holds in general (it does not related to the divergence function). You can see for example Wikipedia and its references: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality.